# Best way to lock two tables while an update is performed

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a system which increments and decrements values and then applies these to a total value. So my tables look like this `increment_value_table`, `decrement_value_table`, `total_value_table`

I have a function called `updateValues` which checks the `increment_value_table` & the `decrement_value_table` for any changes to apply to the `total_value_table` table. Each value also has an `item_id`. So multiple item_ids can be updated simultaneously.

This function works fine as long as it's not called twice at the same time. As it could result in a duplicate `increment` or `decrement`. So I'm trying to think of a way to set it so that only one instance of this function can be running at the same time. The solution needs to be on the database level since there are multiple servers (i.e. a local Boolean or Array wouldn't work)

My current solution/idea is to basically make a table in the database with a unique column `item_id` and each time it tries the update function it checks if the item_id is there or not. If not it tries to insert it. If it successfully inserts it then it performs the updates. After finished it deletes it from the database.

I'm wondering if this is the right approach and/or if this can cause problems?

Please let me know if my question/problem isn't clear enough. I'll try to rephrase it.

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to use [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-transactional-statements.html)

Comment: And you may want to look into triggers if you have a denormalised data model.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks! I've been looking into them and they look great. I left out 1 detail and it's that the increment/decrement tables are in a separate database than the total table is. I wonder if this will cause issues

Comment: @Filburt Ah, I've got it. So I can't make them into the same database but I can make a copy into the other database

Comment: @Filburt Thanks Filburt, this was the answer I was looking for. If you could put this into answer form I'll gladly accept it.